# Custom UIView changes after second call

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

my first question here :D

I've a Swift based iOS App. Everything is under a TabBarController. 
So i call Tab 1 and there is a TableView. I click on a cell and everything is fine except this:

[image]

I try to round the Top corners of a UIView. Now it gets important. I stay on this detail page and change to another Tab.
Now i click on Tab 1 again and:

[image]

It's perfect. But why on the second call? 
The rounded function is called in viewWillAppear. So it should load on the first call.

Anyone an idea?

Many thanks in advance
Florian

Comment: This white view is created from a nib or storyboard or programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the common mistake one does, if you want to change something in your UI just before its appearance on the screen, viewWillAppear is not right place to do, you should always do those stuffs in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Just go through viewController's life cycle -

**viewDidLoad** - Gets Called when the controller's view is loaded into memory.

**viewWillAppear** - Gets called when the view controller's view is about to be added to a view hierarchy. (Note -the view is yet to be added to the view hierarchy).

**viewDidLayoutSubviews** - Gets called when view controller just laid out its subviews. (Note - This is the place if you want to modify your UI just before appearing on screen.)

**viewDidAppear** - Gets called when view controller's view was added to a view hierarchy

Comment: Thank you, so easy. I tried it now in viewDidLayoutSubviews and it works!

Answer (score 0):

If the frame of this view is being calculated programatically based on the size of other views that comes from nib, it won't work if you call it on viewWillAppear because the frames of the views are not setted yet. Try to put it on viewDidAppear method. But if the view comes from storyboard or nib try on the view the methods layoutIfNeeded() or in the superview layoutSubviews(). Hope that helps :)

Comment: i'll keep this functions ins mind :D didn't knew them by now :D Thank you